# Need ultimate parent of click target

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Here's a question about binding click events with jQuery that I'm trying to make sense of.

Say I have a block element I bind a click to, with a paragraph tag inside of it:

```
<div id="testClick" style="width:200px; height:100px'>
     <p>test click</p>
</div>
```

and I bind a click to the div:

```
$('#testClick').bind('click', function(e){ 
    //with parent div (via e.target), do something 
});
```

Now, if I click on the text inside the p tag, `e.target` = the p element, and if I click on the div (around, not on the text) e.target = the div element.  So `e.target` = the object clicked on - i.e. the event is also bound to any children of the element specified.

This is to be expected, but I need operate on the parent div.  and using `e.target` is not a reliable way of getting a reference to the div, because depending where within the div the click occurs e.target returns a different element.  If I use `e.target.parent` to get a reference to the div, this fails when the click occurs in the div around the text.

Is there no simple way to get `e.target` to always and only return the exact element to which the click was initially bound?

(For example, in actionScript there is a property "mouseChildren" that prevents events from firing on children of bound elements)

(Consider all above pseudo code)

Answer (score 5):

`this` will reference the element to which the handler is bound.

```
$('#testClick').bind('click', function(e){ 
    alert( this.id ); 
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/yX499/

---

What happens is that the event bubbles up from the most deeply element clicked all the way to the document root.

If it encounters an element along the way with a handler bound for the type of event that occurred, it invokes that handler.

`e.target` will always reference that deeply nested element, but `this` will reference the element to which the handler is bound, so if the event finds 2 elements with an appropriate handler bound on the way up to the root, `e.target` will not change in the 2 handlers, but `this` will be different based on the bound element.

Comment: soo embarrassed - I'm looking at the trees and didn't see the forest. Thank you!

Comment: @Gordon: FWIW, there is also `event.currentTarget` which always gives the element the current event handler belongs to.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Nice! I didn't know about that one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `this`. jQuery calls your callback with `this` set for your convience:

```
$('#testClick').bind('click', function(e){ 
    $(this).doStuff();
});
```

Comment: I'm an idiot!  Trying to make it too complicated!  Thank you - works perfectly.